# Yún boot from SD card

Tags: arduino-yun, linux, bootloader

I have an Arduino Yún, and it only has 16mb flash onboard for the Linux. I was wondering of it is possible to put a bootloader on the flash that uses the sd card as a rootfs? i want to be able to do more projects on it than those that can fit in 16 MB flash.

Comment: Not an Arduino hero, but I think you're trying to do things with your Yun that you could better do with a raspberry pi. For instance, running Linux...

Comment: I like the Yun because it's smaller and less power-intensive than the R-Pi, and i can use it for stuff that doesnt require a GUI. I asked this mainly because i want to run a Bluetooth stack on it, and the entire bluetooth code is probably going to be bigger than the linux OS it runs on.

Comment: I'm not really sure if there's a full fledged Linux OS running on Yun (and any other Arduino). Did you consider a BT-shield? (see fi. http://makezine.com/projects/connect-an-arduino-to-a-7-bluetooth-serial-module/)

Comment: @puredevotion - The arduino Yun is a 400 Mhz MIPS CPU module running [Linino](https://github.com/arduino/linino) (which *is* linux - it's a fork of OpenWRT), stuck to a ATmega32U4. It's not much different from a rPi at all. Have you looked at the Yun at all? You're answering like it's just a ATmega.

Comment: @TheDoctor - [The Yun draws ~200-300 mA when idle](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=188821.0). The rPi draws pretty much the same when idle. There is likely to be no meaningful difference in power consumption (you'd probably save more power by using a more efficient power adapter).

Comment: The high power ratings of the rPi are because the power supply also runs the USB periperals, so the supply needs to be able to run the rPi + two USB devices. They err on the side of safety.

Comment: Instead of booting from the SD card, would [something like this](http://baldwisdom.com/bootdrive/) which loads a sketch from an SD card work?

Comment: Do you want client or host mode? Also, would you accept an answer that provides an alternative way for BT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the Arduino team finally figured it out:

http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/05/06/time-to-expand-your-yun-disk-space-and-install-node-js/

Comment: In case of future link death, it would be good if you could include the pertinent points from the link in your answer

Answer (score 4):

I am using Yun as well for my projects. I don't boot from SD card, but I store a lot of Python code there and it works for me. I've also seen this article that might be interesting for you. I haven't tried to do it on my Yun but I think it should work... This is example how to install node.js on the Yun (SD card), so in theory you could use the same approach for all additional software you want to run.

[http://linino.org/doku.php?id=wiki:nodejs](http://linino.org/doku.php?id=wiki%3anodejs)

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange! Can you please add more detail to your answer? Answers that are all or mostly links are not acceptable on Stack Exchange because the answer is useless if the site goes down. Maybe just quote a few sentences? Also, *in theory you could use the same approach for all software you run*: Can you expand your answer explaining how to do this? Thanks!